# How to write GraphQL Mutation in Swift without 3rd Party

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, swift5

I want to execute GraphQL in swift without any 3rd party.. I have written following example but it is with Query and i just want to execute it with Mutation only... Can you guys please help me like how can we execute mutation. As of now i am getting 403 Error if using Query

```
    let headers = ["content-type": "application/json"]
    let parameters = ["query": "mutation { createUser(email: \"abc@gmail.com\", password: \"abc@123\") { user{id} } }"] as [String : Any]
    

    print("PARAMETERS :", parameters)
    do {
        
        let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://hostname.com/graphql/")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData as Data
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
               let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                 if (error != nil) {
                   print(error as Any)
                 } else {
                   let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                   print(httpResponse as Any)
                 }
               })

               dataTask.resume()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("CATCH ERROR : ", error)
    }
```

Comment: pass args/variables as query variables - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ... use graphiql/playground to test it, check raw request format/details, recreate in code

Comment: @xadm   Do you have any example like how to write the same in Swift GraphQL request?

Comment: no, I don't use this stack/tech/target ... but you can search on SO, there was many similar examples in js using fetch/axios or curl

Comment: I have checked it.. most of are saying to use Apollo client for GraphQL as they say that first we need to load database schema and then we can execute GraphQL query/Mutation and i want to use with only iOS Framework

Comment: apollo is the most popular graphql client ... search more, there is a lot of other examples without apollo